# Solution of a ODE made by a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a function $x(t)\in C^N$ and a linear differential equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^Na_k\frac{d^k}{dt^k}x(t)=0$$
where the coefficients $a_k\in R$
is it possible to find the solution of this ODE vs. $N$?

Comment: Are $a_k$ constant? If yes, then the answer is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29 If no, then in general you cannot solve explicitly.

Comment: Yes, $a_k$ are constant